# create a virtual monitor on windows 10 with no real monitors

Tags: windows-10, display

at home I have a second computer that has only the power supply and the LAN cable.
The first time I connected the mouse, keyboard and monitor to install a remote access software (I use anydesk), then I disconnected everything except the LAN cable and for months and months I use it without problems, when I connect I see that it "generates" (is the correct term?) a virtual monitor.

I would need something similar to work, I will place a computer that will have to stay on 24/7 to run a program, I would need the exact same situation I have at home, but I wish I could make the resolution of this virtual screen work that is created, in this case it is with the resolution 3640x2160 since when the program works I need that there are several windows open and all well visible, obviously this virtual monitor must remain active even if I disconnect from anydesk and therefore not there are active remote sessions.

is such a thing possible? natively or through third-party software or with particular video cable(but i cant plug any monitor)

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't tested it at UHD - there's generic 'dummy' plugs that supposedly support up to 4k resolution and connect into HDMI (there's an old trick with VGA and resistors) - [here's a teardown of one](https://goughlui.com/2019/06/02/review-teardown-generic-hdmi-cheater-dummy-plug-4k-uhd/). I got mine off aliexpress, but they should be trivial to [google up](https://www.google.com/search?q=dummy%20HDMI%204K)

An alternative for lower resolutions might be to use a video capture device as a dummy video device - there's 4k ones but for 1080p or similar, they both would work as a display out, and a way to 'tap' on the video feed physically to a laptop